# I can't find an error, text-align in th tag

Tags: css

I can't find error, trying this for the last 1h.
Here is page http://kushke.5gbfree.com/SecondPage.html
I want to center "To do list" header

```css
table {
    border: 3px solid orange;
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 100%; 
    text-align: center;
}
td, th {
    color: black;
    border: 2px dashed black;
}    
#th1 {
    padding-right: 160px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <th id="th1" nowrap><h3>To do list</h3></th>
        <th><h3>Done</h3></th>
        <th><h3> Hard</font></h3></th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use the padding property to maintain a certain width for the column of your table. By adding a `padding` property, you lose the center alignment.

So, remove

```
#th1 {
    padding-right: 160px;
    align: center;
}
```

and replace it with the code below:

```
#th1 {
    width: 180px;
    padding: auto;
}
```

Of course, you can set your custom width by modifying the value at the code snippet above.

Comment: :) Great, thanks very much! :)  
Both answers are correct! :) 
I lost my head with this.

Comment: I would suggest you to choose my solution, cause it is content independent. That means if you replace "To do list"' with "Something to do" ( shorter or longer expression ) you won't have to change your css values. 

In any case, you should check on your own which answer satisfies you, and select it, not only because it was the first one.

Comment: Ok, I change my mind, your answer is better because not just of content independant but because you explain it more.

Answer (score 4):

The problem appears to be

```
#th1 {
  padding-right:160px;
}
```

If you need padding, add it to both sides of the th:

```
#th1 {
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
```

Comment: How that padding really function? I am very confused.

Comment: @IvanKušaković Basically, padding adds additional empty space within an element. Your `padding-right: 160px;" forced 160 pixels of empty space on the right of the text which made it appear un-aligned. By adding empty space on both sides, the text appears to be centered.

Comment: Oh, I get it now. Thanks again! Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this to th element: To do list
[image]

Comment: I've done that with style attribute within th tag but forgotten to add padding left. Yes, this is also a good solution. Thanks.

Comment: I will do that when I got the reputation of 15. Now is 13.

Answer (score 1):

Because of your help, I have solved this.

No further comments needed, but if you want upvotes, write anything,
I will respond.

Best regards!

Comment: Please do not use answers for such conclusions. You can accept the correct answer and comment on it to say "thanks" if you want to. If new answers are added, you will be notified automatically, so there is no need for further messages. We are here to help and we are glad to help you, but comments on answers and upvotes are the best way to pay us back :)